# Issue with CSS styles affecting the wrong ID

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I've made this fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/Trblestrife/9HCCU/1/

Basically I'm applying a black background 
    `#000` to the ID `#footer-sec` (line 182), however the black background is being applied to the ID `#footer-prim`.
Confusing!

If someone could give me a hand working out what's happening, if there's something wrong with my semantics or something that'd be great. I'm pretty new to this.

Thanks A

**Edit**
My styling begins in the CSS column at line 150. Sorry to make it so bulky, but I need a quick fix as this is a pretty simple problem so I just copy & pasted my whole reset sheet rather than adding only relevant styles. Sorry again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are floating the `ul` inside `#footer-prim` and `#footer-sec` those elements float outside their parent (resp `#footer-prim` and `#footer-sec`).

The solution is to let the parent know that there are elements inside it that float, by using the following code:

```
#footer-prim, #footer-sec {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Also check the [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9HCCU/12/).

Comment: Of course! I'll keep that in mind in the future. All of your answers work, but this one answers the question best.

Answer (score 0):

Set `float:left`. Try this:

```
#footer-sec {
 background-color: #000;
 color: #999;
 float:left;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9HCCU/7/)

Comment: Both of these are great, but do you have any idea why the styles were being applied to a completely different element?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

Adding: `display: inline-block;`

### CSS:

```
#footer-sec {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #999;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9HCCU/9/)

Comment: Both of these are great, but do you have any idea why the styles were being applied to a completely different element?